# Lemon tree dropping healthy leaves

Tags: indoors, citrus, lemons

I have read a number of posts on the same topic, "healthy" lemon tree dropping leaves, [here](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/56675/41187), [here](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/55730/41187), [here](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/56128/41187), [here](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/51249/41187), [here](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/42473/41187), and even [this post](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/20357/41187) from my same city (Vancouver). The general guidance seems to soil ph (which I need to test) and moisture level issues.

My specific circumstance ... This is one of 8 Lemons and 2 Limes grown from seedling. All either 3 or 4 years old. Kept outdoors in the summer, indoors in winter (14 - 18 °C), under a combination fluorescent regular and grow light and E-facing window. All have been watered lightly (winter) once a week and [citrus fertilizer](https://store.thegreenery.ca/products/evergreen-citrus-30-10-10-400g) or [Schultz](https://www.gardenworks.ca/product/schzultz-plant-food-plus-all-purpose-plant-food-10) alternating every 3-4 weeks (1/2 strength). Misting foliage regularly.

Identified a minor scale infestation (< 50 per plant), so manually inspected leaves on all 10 plants, removed all visible bugs, and applied [dormant tree insecticide](https://harpersgardencentre.ca/products/superior-liquid-insecticide-oil-spray-for-dormant-trees). All the others doing well.

This one suddenly suffering from leaf drop, now 50-60/day and almost gone! All the leaves look healthy, no bugs, no mites that I can see, Looks as if some ring chokes it at the stem then falls off, usually leaving the stub, which then falls.

This was actually the biggest plant of the bunch, and my favourite, so, really want to save it!

- Is there still a bug infestation on this one?
- Watering issue?
- Do we just prune it back and hope for new growth ?

[image: The poor plant]
[image: Leaf stem detail]
[image: Hi-res underside]

Comment: I can see you put a lot of work into putting the photo montage together but this comes with a loss of detail.  Please add one closeup picture of the underside of the leaves, one picture showing how close the plant is to the light and one picture of the top of the soil

Comment: I removed the collage, added a hi-es of the underside of two leaves. The soil has a large of 1" sand on the top to prevent the little flies and burrowing insects from getting in. It was a mix of potting soil and SeaSoil, same as the rest. The plant is located under the 48" florescent fixture, reaching almost to the top; 1x [Sylvania Gro-Luxx](https://www.canadiantire.ca/en/pdp/sylvania-gro-lux-g13-bi-pin-base-plant-aquarium-fluorescent-tube-light-bulb-40w-48-in-0525123p.html), one regular Cool-White tube. E facing window is square, 4 ft away, with other plants alongside. Have moved 'em around.